# How can I get bower_rails to install my Bower assets on Heroku?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, bower

I want to use bower_rails to incorporate bower assets into my Rails application. I don't want to commit these assets into my repo though, I just want to specify them in my Bowerfile and have them installed by Heroku during deployment.

How can I do that?

Comment: You'll probably be better using [`Rails-Assets`](http://rails-assets.org). This creates "gems" of each `Bower` repo you can find, and works 100% on heroku

Comment: Thanks for the comment Richard! I have used it in the past, but I have found that sometimes there aren't the most recent versions of things available and that some assets don't work. I had hoped bower_rails could handle this by installing the assets during Heroku deployment - shouldn't it be able to do that?

Comment: It should do, but you may need a `Proc` file to get it working